# Netlogo: Turtles inherit event from other turtles

Tags: netlogo

How to let other turtles inherit event from other turtle? In my code I have this simple setup that has 50 turtles. I have also a panic button that if it is clicked some turtle will set their mood to panic and color to orange.

I have some changes with this one. Disregard the percentage. Now all turtles will check around them if they found/see turtles with mood = panic and color orange they will also go to panic and color orange.

```
turtles-own[
 mood
]


to setup
  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks
  create-Humans
end


to create-humans
  crt 50[
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set color blue 
    set mood "calm"
  ]
end


to panic
  ask n-of initial-panic turtles [
    set mood "panic"
    set color orange
  ]

end
```

[image: Model image]

I tried this.

```
to go
  ask turtles[
    fd 1
    lt random 90]

  ask turtles[ 
    ask turtles in-cone 3 60
    [ if any? turtles with [ color orange]
        set mood "panic"] ]  

end
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "inherit the panic event"? Do you just want 5% of the other turtles to have their mood set to "panic" and color orange? How do you want these 5% to be selected?

Comment: Yes I want them to set to "panic" and color orange. They must be randomly selected.

Comment: Do you mean?   ask n-of (percent-of-affected * count turtles ) turtles
  [ set color orange
  ]

Comment: I have some changes with this one. Disregard the percentage. Now all turtles will check around them if they found/see turtles with mood = panic and color orange they will also go to panic and color orage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow, you can try this:

```
turtles-own[
 mood
]


to setup
  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks
  create-Humans
  panic
end


to create-humans
  crt 50[
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set color blue 
    set mood "calm"
  ]
end


to panic
  ask n-of initial-panic turtles [
    set mood "panic"
    set color orange
  ]

end


to go


  ask turtles[ 

    fd 1
    lt random 90

    if any? turtles in-cone 3 60 with [ color =  orange]
      [set mood "panic"
        set color orange
      ]
  ] 

end
```